# net of oblique cone,why it has a shape like this?

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

today i was building a right cone for my geometry homework.after building the cone, i started to think what shape the [net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28polyhedron%29) of an oblique cone (cones with circular base which the axis does not pass perpendicularly through the center of the base) would look like. I searched on the internet and I found this(from [here](http://www.korthalsaltes.com/model.php?name_en=special%20cones)):[image]

i'm interested  to know **why the net has a shape like this**.

**Does this shape has an special name?**

And my more general question is: **what is the process to draw net of a 3d object?**

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of analysis you're after ... The upright cone when unfolded is a circular sector, while an oblique cone when unfolded has varying radial distance to the bottom right point (which is to be the vertex of the cone). There should be some constraints to the tangent of the profile besides continuity. For example, it cannot be bimodal.

Comment: This problem is addressed in the following article by Apostol and Mntsakanian:

Tom M. Apostol & Mamikon A. Mnatsakanian (2007) Unwrapping Curves from Cylinders and Cones, The American Mathematical Monthly, 114:5, 388-416, DOI:10.1080/00029890.2007.11920429

In this reference, the mentioned curve is called a generalized ellipse.